# How to tell gorm to save missing time.Time fields as NULL and not '0000-00-00'?

Tags: mysql, go, time, timestamp, go-gorm

I have this custom type for users:

```
type User struct {
    UserID    uint64 `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    LastLogin time.Time
}
```

When passing to gorm's `db.Create()` method, a user is initialised as follows:

```
return User{
    UserID:    userID,
    AccountID: accountID,
    UserType:  userType,
    Status:    status,
    UserInfo:  &userInfo,
    CreatedAt: now,
    UpdatedAt: now,
}
```

Because `LastLogin` is a nullable `timestamp` column in MySQL, I didn't initialise its value here.

Now gorm will parse the unset value to `'0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000'` in the SQL statement, and cause the following error.

```
Error 2021-01-29 15:36:13,388 v1(7) error_logger.go:14 192.168.10.100 - - default - 0 Error 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00' for column 'last_login' at row 1
```

While I understand how MySQL doesn't allow zero timestamp values without having to change some modes, I can easily initialise the time.Time field to be some faraway dates, e.g. 2038-ish. How do I tell gorm to just pass the zero Time field as NULL in the SQML instead?

Comment: Maybe change the type of `LastLogin` to `sql.NullTime`

Comment: try definiting it as `LastLogin *time.Time`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So you have a couple of options here. You can make `LastLogin` a pointer which will mean it can be a `nil` value:

```
type User struct {
    ID        uint64 `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    LastLogin *time.Time
}
```

Or like @aureliar mentioned you can use the sql.NullTime type

```
type User struct {
    ID        uint64 `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    LastLogin sql.NullTime
}
```

Now when you create that object in the DB and do not set LastLogin it will save as NULL in the DB.

https://gorm.io/docs/models.html

It's worth noting, if you use sql.NullTime, in the struct you will see a default timestamp rather than a nil value

Comment: How to assign nil value to LastLogin?

Comment: @UysimTy I think this can be like `user.LastLogin = sql.NullTime{}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DEFAULT NULL` in your `gorm` tag like this:

```golang
type User struct {
    UserID    uint64 `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    LastLogin time.Time `gorm:"type:TIMESTAMP;null;default:null"`
}
```

In this case `gorm` would not insert a zero value of `0000-00-00 00:00:00` for `LastLogin`.

Comment: All that's strictly necessary is `gorm:"default:null"`

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
type Test struct {
    ID uint64 `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id"`
    CompletedAt sql.NullTime `gorm:"type:TIMESTAMP NULL"`
}
```

It helps to make CompletedAt  field nullable timestamp type

Comment: Hey thanks. I figure this is only meant for DB initialisation. In my case, since the DB is created without using gorm, my issue was just about storing null timestamp. So I guess this isn't the answer I was looking for, but thanks! One approach as some pointed out earlier is to represent the time.Time instance in Go using a pointer.